# Server Side Includes using browserSync-SSI and gulp?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm having an issue getting server side includes to work using browserSync and browsersync-ssi. I'm trying to stick a default header and footer file into each page using includes.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/browsersync-ssi

gulpfile.js:

```
 var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
 var ssi = require('browsersync-ssi');    

 gulp.task('serve', function(done) {
  browserSync({
    server: {
    baseDir: ['./template'],
       middleware: ssi({
          baseDir: __dirname + '/template',
          ext: '.shtml',
          version: '1.4.0'
       })
    },
});
```

Inside my /template folder I have two files:

page.html containing:

```
    <!--#include virtual="./header.shtml" -->
```

and header.shtml containing some HTML markup

According to the examples this should work, can anyone spot where i have gone wrong? Is there an easier or different way to inject a header\footer into every page?